# Gmail Star like Bookmarking using jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to create a star like bookmarking using jQuery. Unfortunately what I have is only working one way. That means if a link is unstarred then it stars it successfully but if a link is already starred and I want to unstar it then the star image disappears completely from the page, however in the back end it does work but in the front end the star image goes off completely.

I have the following in my HTML:

```
require_once('connection.inc.php');
$con = dbConnect('read');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM trn_bookmark";
$result = $con->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error());
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $className  = "star";
    if($row['bookmark_flag'] == 'Y'){
        $className = "favorited";
    }
    echo '<div id="'.$row['bookmark_id'].'"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="'.$className.'"></a> <span>'.$row['bookmark_desc'].'</span></div>';
}
```

CSS:

```
.star {
background-color: transparent;
background-image: url('star-off.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
display: block;  
height:16px;
width:16px;
float:left;
}
.favorited {
 text-indent: -5000px;
background-color: transparent;
background-image: url('star-on.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;   
height:16px;
width:16px;
float:left;
}
```

The JavaScript function is this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
 $('.star,.favorited').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).parents('div').attr('id');             
        var className = $(this).attr('class');
        var flag  = (className=='star') ? 'Y':'N';
        var $this = $(this);
        $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "conversation.php",
                cache: false,               
                data:{'bookmarkId': id,'flag':flag},
                success: function(response){
                    if(response=='true'){                               
                        $this.toggleClass("favorited");
                    }   
                },
                error: function(){                      
                    alert('Error while request..');
                }
             });
  });
});
```

And the conversation.php:

```
$bookmarkId = $_POST['bookmarkId'];
$flag = $_POST['flag'];
require_once('connection.inc.php');
$con = dbConnect('read');
$stmt = $con->stmt_init();
$sql = "UPDATE trn_bookmark SET bookmark_flag = ? WHERE bookmark_id = '$bookmarkId'";
    if ($stmt->prepare($sql)) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $flag);
        $done = $stmt->execute();
    }

    echo 'true';
```

I have uploaded it so that you can see what is happening live. You can see what is happening here in this link: http://www.rytenet.com/starrating/index.php

Comment: No problems on latest Chrome on OS X.

Comment: Ditto on Windows 7 using Chrome

Comment: @Josso: Did you reload the page after starring and before unstarring? OP: the class is completely gone. And why the extra `) ` after `class="'.$className.'"`?

Comment: instead of var flag  = (className=='star') ? 'Y':'N'; use var flag  = $(this).hasClass('star') ? 'Y':'N';

Comment: Yes, exactly, Did you reload the page after starring and before unstarring? OP: the class is completely gone. Star all of them and then refresh the webpage and then try to unstar them and you will see th problem.

Comment: @TamilSelvan Thanks for help but that also didn't work. I still see same problem.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel Yes you got the problem. This is exactly what i am geetting.. Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

When page load if star is favourite it store $className = "favorited" not className="star favorited"

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $className  = "star";
    if($row['bookmark_flag'] == 'Y'){
        $className .= " favorited";
    }
    echo '<div id="'.$row['bookmark_id'].'"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="'.$className.'"></a> <span>'.$row['bookmark_desc'].'</span></div>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tamil Selvan for your help. It's working just fine now.